# Fix for Visual Studio 2012 Mouse Pointer

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I think I mistakenly hit some unknown key sequence in Visual Studio. Now, my mouse is this horrible/useless square box in the GUI instead of the default arrow.

Here is a video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo1oqg2Wl5k

Does anyone know how to change that back?

The closest issue I found related to this was [szalski's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16320355/153923). It did not solve my issue, though. It just turned the box black.

Is there a way to embed the video instead of leaving a hard link?

**Update:**

The Right-Click the controls and resetting the toolbox did NOT fix this oddity.

I wished this guy had posted his solution:

[Square mouse pointer in Visual Studio 2008 designer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998092/153923)

**RESOLUTION**

[Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)' recommendation fixed this.

[image: Hans]

Comment: Does right-clicking on any item in the ToolBox window, selecting "Reset Toolbox" and then selecting pointer from the top help you?

Comment: Not at the Right-Click, Elizion. I'll look to see if I can find that elsewhere. That trick sounds familiar.

Comment: Re: update. I guess you sympathise with this guy: [xkcd.com/979/](http://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: Andrew, that was so awesome I had to update the question to include that pic.

Comment: Visual Studio has no such button.  Reboot your machine to eliminate video driver corruption as a cause.

Comment: If Hans' suggestion doesn't work, you could try a different cursor in Control Panel -> Mouse properties. Also, it might be that the cursor shadow is the thing going wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant - you are the man! I typically hibernate my PC after work, Monday - Friday, then shut it down for the weekend. I wouldn't have realized it was just a corrupt video driver for almost a week. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow allows you to provide an answer to your own question for just such occasions.